# Annotations of Annotations in Java 5/6

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am setting up Hibernate Caching and want to cache certain entities in different regions. For example, some entities can be "stale" for up to 5 minutes, some for an hour, and some (like lookups) won't change for weeks. To facilitate easy config of regions in my code, I'm trying the following:

I created an annotation named `@LookupCache` (and `@DailyCache` etc)

```
@Cache(region = "lookups", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LookupCache {}
```

And I am adding that annotation to my Hibernate/JPA entity:

```
@LookupCache
public class Course {}
```

This way, I can easily change the region or attributes of the `@LookupCache` without having to change the annotation params of every class.

However, the cache loader doesn't pick up this inherited `@Cache` notation. How do I get the `@LookupCache` annotation to inherit the annotations that are applied to it?

Update: To clarify, the @Cache annotation is a built-in hibernate annotation used by second-level caches like EHCache. I can't modify the @Cache annotation to make it inheritable by other annotations (my client doesn't want to maintain a special fork of hibernate). This is probably my only option though.

Comment: Annotations don't work like that, I'm afraid. There's no "inheritance" like what you're looking for, it's up to Hibernate to do that explicitly, which won't happen because it's a custom annotation.

Comment: So much for DRY. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example that shows how to retrieve details of the @Cache annotation applied to your @LookupCache annotation:

```
Course c = new Course();
LookupCache lookupCache = c.getClass().getAnnotation(LookupCache.class);
Cache cache = lookupCache.annotationType().getAnnotation(Cache.class);
System.err.println("region " + cache.region());
System.err.println("usage " + cache.usage());
```

You just need to make sure that @Cache annotation also has @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

Comment: This is the receipe I was looking for reading annotations's annotations! Since the getClass().getAnnotations() was returning proxies!